# How do I duplicate the presentation functionality for HTML5Rocks.com?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, html

When you go to http://slides.html5rocks.com/ you can see the entire presentation (with a previous and next slide peeking from the sides - all while it is relative to the screen size of the user).

How do I do that with jQuery + HTML5? I just want to have a bunch of images (think a photo gallery) that can be cycled through like that. When you are on the current image, you see the previous and next images peeking from the sides. Also allow the user to go to the next/previous slide with the keyboard.

It would also be cool to be able to adjust it using the same commands (ctrl/command + '+/-') for zooming.

Answer (score 1):

I am very impressed with the simplicity/power of the jQuery UI Tools -

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

They do almost everything you want (and I'd be surprised if there isn't some way in the tool kit to do the key commands - if not, use this: http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/)

Comment: Thanks...the gallery doesn't really give me what I need. It feels too photo gallery-ish. I really want to duplicate the functionality of the html5rocks presentation.

The hotkeys script is a good start though.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's extremely powerful. What you want to do is have the advance method take it 100% the size of your object, but then make the display window 100% + x% for each side.